# Win32 : set default font and text color for rich edit

Tags: c++, winapi

It should be an easy question but I was unable to find an answer on google:
How to set a default font and color to a richedit using plain c++ and win32 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> You can also use EM_SETCHARFORMAT and EM_GETCHARFORMAT messages to set and retrieve the character formatting of the insertion point, which is the formatting that is applied to any subsequently inserted characters. For example, if an application sets the default character formatting to bold and the user then types a character, that character is bold.

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN also

> Rich Edit 4.1: To set the default font for a script, call
>   EM_SETCHARFORMAT with CHARFORMAT2, specifying values for the yHeight,
>   bCharSet, bPitchAndFamily, szFaceName, and lcid members. Also, to get
>   the default font for a specific code page, call EM_GETCHARFORMAT with
>   CHARFORMAT2, specifying values for the bCharSet and lcid members.